# If $f: \mathbb{R^{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function and $f(0)=0$ then...

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

... prove that there exist functions $g_{i}:\mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i} g_{i}(x).$$
Well, my fist attempt is to use linear algebra and think of the functions $g_{i}$ as a base. Then I need to prove these function generates the set of the codomain of $f$ and also that they're linear independent, and here is where I use the fact that $f(0)=0$.

But I not sure how can I use the fact that $f$ is differentiable. Maybe saying that is a linear transformation that is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $f(x)=\int_0^1df(tx)dt=\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x_i{{\partial f(tx)}\over{\partial x_i}}dt$.

Write $g_i(x)=\int_0^1{{\partial f(tx)}\over{\partial x_i}}dt$.

Comment: So you are saying that we can understand $f(x)$ as the sum of it's partials?